# Sorting collection of maps based on values

Tags: java-stream

I'm trying to sort list of maps based on specific key lets say "tax" with int values in all the maps. However other keys like "id" and "price" have string and double type values respectively as shown below.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> taxes = Arrays.asList(Map.of("id", "3", "tax", 25, "price", 8.05),
            Map.of("id", "9", "tax", 37, "price", 16.05), Map.of("id", "2", "tax", 19, "price", 9.25),
            Map.of("id", "11", "tax", 28, "price", 16.05));
```

I want to sort list of maps with highest tax value to lowest tax value. I'm trying with below approach but getting error at m.get("tax").

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(map -> map.get("tax")).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());`
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Object'

Comment: How is your List declared?

Comment: List<Map<String, Object>>

Comment: I have list of four maps as below and want to sort them based on the values of tax key.[{id=3, tax=25}, {id=9, tax=37}, {id=2, tax=19}, {id=11, tax=7}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because compile could not interpret the type of object in a lambda expression, you can solve it but just interpreting `map` as `Map<String, Integer>`

```
list.stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map<String,Integer> map) -> map.get("tax")).reversed())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this is not completely fixed and it will fail when `tax` is not presenting in any `Map` or having `null` as value, you can solve that using `Comparator.nullsFirst` or `Comparator.nullsLast`

```
List<Map<String,Integer>> taxes = List.of(Map.of("id",3, "tax",25),
            Map.of("id",9, "tax",37),Map.of("id",2, "tax",19),
            Map.of("id",11));

List<Map<String,Integer>> results = taxes.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map<String,Integer> map)->map.get("tax"),Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

 System.out.println(results);   //[{tax=37, id=9}, {tax=25, id=3}, {tax=19, id=2}, {id=11}]
```

Comment: I think it is a little cleaner to do it like this. `List<Map<String, Integer>> results = taxes.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(map->map.get("tax"),
Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder()))).collect(Collectors.toList());`